# PHP 'global variable'

Tags: php

I am creating a game in PHP, and am having a problem with global variables. Depending on which button is pressed in my HTML page, a corresponding PHP script is run and a function is called depening on the `isset` function.

My question is this: I want to keep a score variable, and I would like to have access to this variable in the future after multiple `post` statements have been issued.

I have tried using the `global` keyword but this does not seem to do what I am expecting.

Can I please have some help with this?

Comment: Variables in php (either local or global) live for only one http request. If you need to keep the data across several http requests - you need to persist it somewhere.

Comment: I would recommend using ajax, to submit and pull the current score, to ensure that your data is up to date and accurate.

Comment: search for something like "php store cookies"

Comment: **Store it in a session** like `$_SESSION['user_score']`

Answer (score 0):

Memcache may be the most optimal solution, but that requires special setup and usually a dedicated setup.

Much more accessible for most developers is a MySQL database to save the score and retrieve it with each request.

Comment: "Much more accessible for most developers is a MySQL database to save the score and retrieve it with each request." This sounds like what I am looking for. Can you please point me in the correct direction to look into this? thanks.

Comment: Every webhost I have laid eyes on, except some "free" hosts, give you access to a database. You should ask them about the specifics.

Comment: Is it something to do with the isset function, but with a variable instead of say a POST statement?

Comment: You asking that question makes me think you're probably the least qualified person to make a game. Your obsession with the `isset()` function is completely unfounded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). Google up and you can find some excellent tutorials on both of them.